# Merge 2 pandas Dataframe with a condition other than equality

Tags: python, performance, pandas, merge

I need to merge 2 dataframes in function of a variable but I need an other merge condition than the equality. 
My first dataframe (350 lines):

```
var11   var12
id11    [a, b, c]
id12    [d, a]
id13    [e, f]
```

My second dataFrame (1 million lines approx.):

```
var21   var22
id21    [a, b, e, g]
id22    [d, a, q]
id23    [d, a, b]
```

I would like to merge those 2 dataframes with the condition that the length of the intersection of the lists of each var22 and var12 is higher or equal than 2.

What I would like to get :

```
var11   var12       correspondance
id11    [a, b, c]      id21
id11    [a, b, c]      id23
id12    [d, a]         id23
id12    [d, a]         id22
id13    [e, f]         NaN
```

I already have a solution using `map` and a `lambda` funtion that iterates over the other dataframe but it takes too much time in Python, especially given the size of my dataframes. I was wondering if there was an easy way of doing it with Pandas or any other way in Python. If not I may consider using a Database.

Hope I made myself clear enough, don't hesitate to tell me if I was not.

edit:

My Solution, I agregate all in a list:

```
df1["correspondance"] = df1["var12"].map(lambda x : [item[1]["var21"] for item in df2.iterrows() if len(x.intersection(item[1]["var22"]))>1])
```

Comment: Do you mind to share your solution first?

Comment: I could do it with an apply and a loop and it's (off course slow).

Comment: Do you have a lot of possible values in var12 and var22? But it just looks like an expensive computation that will take a long time to run whatever implementation you do.

Comment: @MikhailVenkov Yeah, all different values... I know it will tak a long time to run but if I could save some minutes it would be great